# SAP Crystal Report - How to override default formatting for number and currency field in formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using `tonumber` function but its adding default formatting and I don't want that mainly thousand separator.
Also, for currency, I don't want currency symbol.
As I am using these fields in formula field, I cannot set properties, right?

Comment: post how are you are getting and how want it to be.. A sample data will be helpful... how can we assume things

Answer (score 0):

To remove the thousand separator, I generally do something like

```
Replace(ToText(YourField),',','')
```

To remove currency symbols do the same

```
Replace(ToText(YourField),'£','')
```